# error passing 'const' as 'this' argument

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-flags

I'm stuck on an error from so long now, the following, I'm learning and I think I don't understand the error.

```
 droid.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Droid&)’: 

droid.cpp:94:30: error: passing ‘const Droid’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::string 

Droid::getId()’ discards qualifiers
 [-fpermissive]
```

the line 94:

```
std::ostream&   operator<<(std::ostream &os, Droid const & a)
    os << "Droid '" << a.getId() << "', " << *a.getStatus() << ", " << a.getEnergy() << std::endl;
```

and hearders :

```
std::string   getId();
```

I have the same error for the 3 calls in "operator<<", a.getId, a.getStatus, a.getEnergy.

Can someone could explain to me what the compiler is saying?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to make that method `const` so it can be called on a `const` instance or via a `const` reference:

```
std::string   getId() const;
                      ^^^^^
```

The same would apply to all `Droid` methods called in `std::ostream&   operator<<(std::ostream &os, Droid const & a)`.

You will also need to add the `const` in the method's definition.

Comment: @juanchopanza Would you mind please to mention how is it called? I would like to understand why I need to declare `const` on reference explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

You need `std::string   getId() const;`. Otherwise, the compiler thinks `getId()` might change the instance, which you can't do on a `const Droid&`. Same thing for `getStatus()` and `getEnergy()`.